# System.NotSupportedException in TaskScheduler when using PublishTrimmed .NET6.0

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, .net-6.0

I want to use TaskScheduler using "TaskScheduler 1.1 Type Library" from Add COM Reference.

```
using TaskScheduler;
...
     ITaskService taskservice = null;
     taskservice = new TaskScheduler.TaskScheduler(); <=NotSupportedException
     taskservice.Connect(null, null, null, null);
```

But the above code will cause an exception.

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Built-in COM has been disabled via a feature switch. See https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/com for more

If PublishTrimmed is set to false, no exception will be raised.
However, I don't want to set it to false because it will increase the size of the exe.

project file is following

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
    <PublishTrimmed>true</PublishTrimmed>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I try to add assembly to TrimmerRootAssembly. But following is not worked.

```
<ItemGroup>
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="TaskScheduler" />
    <TrimmerRootAssembly Include="Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Seems like trimming with COM references has been disabled by default due to issues it might cause.
You can re-enable it by adding `<BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>` to your `PropertyGroup` in your csproj file.

You can also use ComWrappers to get proper AOT interop solution in .NET 5 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/tutorial-comwrappers