# Cannot copy Guna control in Visual Studio Winforms designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, .net-7.0

I am using Winforms on .NET 7.0 and installed guna package. I create a button and want to copy it, but when copying, I get an error

> An error occurred while processing this command. built-in com has been disabled via a feature switch

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
        <RootNamespace>Create_Effect_.NET_7._0</RootNamespace>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <PublishAot>true</PublishAot>
        <_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>true</_SuppressWinFormsTrimError>
        <PublishTrimmed>false</PublishTrimmed>
        <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Guna.UI2.WinForms" Version="2.0.4.4" />
        <PackageReference Include="WinFormsComInterop" Version="0.4.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Here is a screenshot illustrating the error:

[image: here is a picture showing the error]

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110207/system-notsupportedexception-in-taskscheduler-when-using-publishtrimmed-net6-0

Comment: as you see i added <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport> already but it is not working

Comment: You have `<PublishAot>true</PublishAot>` in there and it's not a Console app (and no built-in COM). What are you trying to do?

Comment: Good odds that the mysterious "feature switch" is in fact PublishAot.  Can't work for a Winforms app, you have to get rid of it.

Comment: This error is generally a problem with COM interop. Does this issue occur when you perform COM interop in other projects?