# Fix MDAC n IIS10

Tags: oledb, visual-foxpro, iis-10, mdac

I have 32bit API wrote in C#.net 7. That API needs access FOX PRO DBF files using OLEDB drive (32bits). (if exist 64 bits drive do that job, please let me know, so I can upgrade)

All work on IISExpress, on VS2022 Environments (dev, stage, and prod).

I did deploy to IIS 10 on my Local PC, The API run. the issue happens when we request data.

I get this:

##### Curl

```
curl -X 'GET' \
  'http://localhost:15080/excessiveReturns' \
  -H 'accept: application/json'
```

##### Request URL

```
http://localhost:15080/excessiveReturns
```

##### Server response

CodeDetails500UndocumentedError: Internal Server ErrorResponse bodyDownload

{ "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6.1",

"title": "An error occurred while processing your request.", "status": 500,

"detail": "The data providers require Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC). Please install Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) version 2.6 or later. - Built-in COM has been disabled via a feature switch. See https://aka.ms/dotnet-illink/com for more information."

}

Response headers content-type: application/problem+json date: Sat,30 Sep 2023 00:16:10 GMT server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 transfer-encoding: chunked x-powered-by: ASP.NET

I did install MDAC 2.8. reboot my pc. But, the issue still persists

Please any advice to fix this issue?

I appreciate in advance.

I did install MDAC 2.8. reboot my pc. But, the issue still persists

Comment: If you are so willing to upgrade, please use a modern relational database (so many choices, commercial or open source to choose from).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I think you will find someone that can help you on the www.West-Wind.com website.  Select the Support option on the menu and the Message Board there is very active with users that have a lot of Foxpro knowledge.  Good luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was focus on the first part of the error message: "The data providers require Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC). Please install Microsoft Data Access Components (MDAC) version 2.6 or later"

I found the solution when I search with second part the error message : "Built-in COM has been disabled via a feature switch." the I found this link: [System.NotSupportedException in TaskScheduler when using PublishTrimmed .NET6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68110207/system-notsupportedexception-in-taskscheduler-when-using-publishtrimmed-net6-0)

The solution for this issue  is BuiltInComInteropSupport in the project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
...
     <BuiltInComInteropSupport>true</BuiltInComInteropSupport>
</PropertyGroup>
```